# I did this problem intuitively, But I don't know if my think of solving this problem is right

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, word-problem

So here is the question: 
A rectangular tank with base 4 feet by 5 feet and a height of 4 feet is full of water. The water weighs 62.4 pounds per cubic foot. How much work is done in pumping the water out over the top edge in order to empty A) half of the tank. B) all of the tank.

So what I did was the following; Since the weight equal force F we have F = 62.4-lbs
And the volume of a rectangle is l.b.h, so that is 4.5.4 = 80 ft^3 Then I just plug in using integrals.

A)
w = 80 from 0 to 1/2 of 62.4 dx and that is equal to 62.4x and then I substitute and I got 2496 ft-lbs Which is the correct answer according to my book.

B)

w = 80 from 0 to 2 of 62.4 dx and that is equal to 62.4x and then I substitute and I got 9984 ft-lb which is correct. 
Now my question is, is the process of doing this correct?. I used common sense to set up the limit of integration.

Comment: well, you have the rate of water being pumped, and the height it needs to be pumped, and the weight of the water. the rate of water pumped and the weight is constant, whereas your real integral lies in the increasing distance it must be pumped

Comment: Are you supposed to release the water at the top of the wall? If you use a siphon to let out the water at the level of the _bottom_ of the tank you don't have to add any work at all.

Comment: wait isnt that what osmosis is? siphons sound like magic tbh